# Heartbeat (without ldirectord etc) for a floating IP address?

Tags: failover, high-availability, heartbeat, ldirectord

I have two load-balancing servers running mod_proxy_balancer. Each server balances between two web servers.

Now I'd like to find a way to share a single IP address between those two load-balancing servers, in a way that will fail over.

Is it possible to use just heartbeat (without ldirectord) to share an IP address, with mod_proxy_balancer?

If so, could someone point me at some instructions, or suggest the way to proceed?

All the heartbeat tutorials I've seen assume that you're using ldirectord, or pacemaker (which I can't use because of restrictions on my cloud servers).

Comment: Perhaps this? http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/5862?page=0,0

Answer (score 1):

You can use the IPaddr / IPaddr2 Resource Agent in Heartbeat to accomplish this.  In your haresources file (under /etc/ha.d/ for me) you would add a line like

```
IPaddr::172.16.20.160
```

If Heartbeat is already running, you'll need to start the resource manually

```
/etc/ha.d/resource.d/IPaddr 172.16.20.160 start
```

If for any reason the server that the IP is active on fails, the secondary will pick up the resource automagically.

You do not need ldirectord or pacemaker for this.